# Google Docs Sheets - Strip text from result

Tags: xml, excel, google-sheets, google-docs

I have this code:

```
=ImportXML("http://www.site.co.uk/content?q=test", "//div[@id='searchCount']")
```

In the data it returns this:

```
Items 1 to 10 of 1,819
```

How can I change the formular to strip off the "Items X to X of " so I only get left with the number at the end please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(ImportXML("http://www.site.co.uk/content?q=test", "//div[@id='searchCount']")," "),1,COLUMNS(SPLIT(ImportXML("http://www.site.co.uk/content?q=test", "//div[@id='searchCount']")," ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this might also work:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(ImportXML("http://www.site.co.uk/content?q=test", "//div[@id='searchCount']"), "of (.+)$")+0
```